# Out sample-rolling window-forecasts R

Tags: r

I am trying to use a rolling window using linear regression. I don't know how I should store the output from forecast into a variable, which I could use for plotting ant etc.

```
predict.1 <- function(P){

  results <- rep(0, P)

  for( i in 0:2){

    y1<-window(y,start=1937+i,end=1966+i)
    x1<-window(ll,start=1937+i,end=1966+i)
    dx2<-window(ll,start=1937+i,end=1966+i)
    in.sample<-data.frame(y1,x1,x2)
    names(in.sample)<-c("Outcome","Predictor1","Predictor2")
    x1.pred<-window(x1,start=1967+i,end=1967+i)
    x2.pred<-window(x2,start=1967+i,end=1967+i)
    out.sample<-data.frame(x1.pred,x2.pred)
    new.data<-out.sample
    names(new.data)<-c("Predictor1","Predictor2")
    results[i]<-predict(lm(Outcome~Predictor1+Predictor2,data=in.sample),new.data,se.fit=TRUE)  

  }
  results
}
```

I receive this message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In results[i] <- predict(lm(Outcome ~ Predictor1 + Predictor2, data = in.sample),  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In results[i] <- predict(lm(Outcome ~ Predictor1 + Predictor2, data = in.sample),  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length.
```

I don't know how to overcome the problem.

Comment: `predict` returns you a vector or matrix so your vector named results is not the right object to store it. what is the outcome of `predict` in your case, i.e. what is the result of `str(predict(...))` ?